# nodejs async series final callback fires before other functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function(){ console.log("2"); }, 1000 * 10);
        callback();
    },
    function(callback) {
        console.log("1"); }, 1000 * 10);
        callback();
    },
], function(err) { 
      console.log("done");
 });
```

I am trying to execute above code. I expect the result to be
1
2
done

But I get the result as
1
done
2

Can someone help me on why the final callback is executing before series callbacks?

Comment: You have an extra closing bracket in the second function call. It's `console.log("1"); }` <--- that extra bracket

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot be compiled

```
 function(callback) {
        console.log("1"); }, 1000 * 10);
        callback();
 }
```

I think you want to write :

```
function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function(){ console.log("1"); }, 1000 * 10);
        callback();
},
```

I think you must use the promise instead of async lib.

Something similar :

```
new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log("1"); resolve(); }, 1000 * 10);
})
.then(() => {
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log("2"); Promise.resolve(); }, 1000 * 10);
    })
.then(() => {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the `callback` argument is that you call it when the asynchronous task, in your case `setTimeout`, has completed.

When the time-out time has been reached, the function argument to `setTimeout` gets called, which is also when you should call `callback`:

```
async.series([
  function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log("1"); callback(); }, 1000 * 10);
  },
  function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() { console.log("2"); callback(); }, 1000 * 10);
  },
], function(err) { 
  console.log("done");
});
```

Because each entry is called in series, the code will be executed like this:

- wait 10 seconds
- output `1`
- call `callback` to go to the next entry
- wait 10 seconds
- output `2`
- call `callback` to go to the final function
- output `done`